# Trying to get property 'uid' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, belongs-to, has-one

In blade I'm trying to determine which button needs to show, but I get the following error:
Trying to get property 'uid' of non-object.

In my Entry model I made this relation:

```
public function blockeduser() {
    return $this->hasOne(BlockedUser::class);
}
```

In my BlockedUser model I made this relation:

```
public function entry() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Entry::class);
}
```

The code in the blade file:

```
@foreach($entries as $entry)
<tr>
    <td style="max-width: 150px;">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <form target="_blank" method="post" action="{{route('entries.show', $entry->id)}}">
                @method("GET")
                <button style="margin-right: 5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">View</button>
            </form>

            @if ($entry->uid !== $entry->blockeduser->uid)
                <form method="post" action="{{route('entries.blockUser', $entry->id)}}">
                    @csrf
                    <button style="margin-right: 5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Block</button>
                </form>

            @else
                <form method="post" action="{{route('entries.unblockUser', $entry->id)}}">
                    @csrf
                    <button style="margin-right: 5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Unblock</button>
                </form>
            @endif

            <form method="post" action="{{route('entries.destroy', $entry->id)}}">
                @csrf
                @method("DELETE")

                <button style="margin-right: 5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

How can I access the uid inside the blocked users table that has a relation with the Entry and compare them and determine which form needs te show.

Or is there a way I can check if a table contains a row that has a relation with the Entry?

Possible solution?

Because `$entry->blockeduser->uid` was not found I edited the if statement inside the blade file:

```
@if ($entry->blockeduser == null)
<form method="post" action="{{route('entries.blockUser', $entry->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <button style="margin-right: 5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Block</button>
</form>

@elseif ($entry->blockeduser !== null)
<form method="post" action="{{route('entries.unblockUser', $entry->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <button style="margin-right: 5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Unblock</button>
</form>
@endif
```

Comment: `@foreach($entry->blockeduser as $blockeduser)` It is a hasOne relationship.  Why will you loop?

Comment: Your dd() doesn't show if it's an array or object or what.

Comment: My bad, just trying things without thinking.

Comment: No it's not showing if it's an array or object.

Comment: It could be an Eloquent or Collection instance?

Comment: I think it's a Eloquent instance, can I check this?

Comment: dd() should show you this. Are you checking with Postman by chance?

Comment: No I'm not using Postman right now. I found a solution, but It doesn't feel like the right one. I'll update my post with the 'solution'.

Answer (score 0):

check if `$entry->blockeduser` exists before you check the `uid` inside that like this:

```
if ($entry->blockeduser instanceof \App\Models\BlockedUser && $entry->uid !== $entry->blockeduser->uid)
```

Comment: {{dd($entry->blockeduser instanceof \App\Models\BlockedUser)}} returns true, but $entry->blockeduser->uid still doesn't work.

Comment: that's because your ```$entry->blockeduser``` is empty

Answer (score 0):

you can use optional global helper if `$entry`  is null not throw exception

```php
optional($entry)->uid;
```